# Ubuntu Bionic Beaver - How to modify Window Resize behavior on screen edges

Tags: unity, window-manager, system-settings

I like to have my Windows resized to top half and bottom half when I drag it to their respective spot. The hotcorner actions used to be modifiable directly from the simple settings. Now, there's no indication what so ever of where that might be. It is not an option in the Tweaks menu, either.

Browsed the doc real quick and can't find anything.

**Without using Compiz Grid, is there a way to customize Window Resizing HotCorners?**